# V8 Heap Size Limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I have a simple Node method that allocates an array:

```js
function allocateArray(size) {
    let arr = Array(size).fill('Hello World');

    console.log(`Array size: ${arr.length}`);
    console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics());
    console.log();
}

allocateArray(1e7);
```

When I run the script with the command `node --max-heap-size=16 test.js`, I'm presented with the following heap statistics, which seems that the used heap size is much higher than the heap size limit:

```
Array size: 10000000
{
  total_heap_size: 85463040,
  total_heap_size_executable: 524288,
  total_physical_size: 84758848,
  total_available_size: 2217024,
  used_heap_size: 82159392,
  heap_size_limit: 16777216,
  malloced_memory: 16384,
  peak_malloced_memory: 418144,
  does_zap_garbage: 0,
  number_of_native_contexts: 1,
  number_of_detached_contexts: 0
}
```

How is this possible?

> Note: I've also tried running with `--max-old-space-size` with similar results.

Comment: Where do you find documentation for `--max-heap-size`?  I don't see it in the [node.js command line doc](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html).

Comment: It's in the V8 documentation, also if you run `node --v8-options` you can see it.

Comment: @Eric did you ever find an answer to this question?